# Downloading PDFs opened in new tab with CasperJS

Tags: phantomjs, casperjs

I'm trying to write a casperJS program that can navigate and download PDFs. If I can grab an actual URL corresponding to the PDF it's pretty straight-forward, but that isn't always the case. To test this, I've been working with this simple example locally:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 class="page-title">Hello</h1>
    <a id='1' href="test.pdf" target="_blank">one</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Basic casper:

```
casper.start('file:///opt/templates/templates/src/main/resources/casperjs/example.html').then(function() {
  this.echo('started')
});

casper.then(function() {
  this.waitForSelector('a', function() {
    this.click('a');
  });
});

casper.wait(1000, function() {
  this.echo(JSON.stringify(this.popups[0]));
});

casper.run();
```

When I run this, the (only) popup that's present is a blank HTML page that never loads. It's also worth noting that if you test this without the 'target="_blank"' (i.e. the PDF opens in the same tab), the 'resource.received' event will be emitted (with null content type), but loading the resource will fail:

```
[warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail: file:///opt/templates/templates/src/main/resources/casperjs/test.pdf
```

Is there any good way to handle links that will open/download PDFs in some generic way? You can hook into 'navigation.requested' perhaps and download there, but I don't think there's a wonderful way to figure out that the nav is for a PDF (the URL may not always have file extension).

Comment: [full path is needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme#Unix)

Comment: Sorry for any confusion, I'm using full paths here; I just shortened them in the example for simplicity but I guess that had the opposite effect...